# Logging a Facebook user into CakePHP app if authenticated and user exists in DB

Tags: php, facebook, cakephp

I have built a very simple CakePHP application to test out a possible implementation of the Facebook PHP SDK whereby users can signup either using the app or Facebook and can also login using the app or Facebook. But because the user can do things on the app, they will also have a user account on the app even if they login/register via their Facebook account.

So far I have created the two methods for handling auth and getting user info:

```
// Asks user to authenticate
public function facebook()
{
    $params = array(
      'redirect_uri' => 'http://domain.com/users/signupfacebook',
      'scope'=> 'email',
      'display' => 'popup'
    );

    $loginUrl = $this->Facebook->Sdk->getLoginUrl($params);

    // Need to know if user is already a user on OUR app
    // If true log them in. If false redirect to signup form like below

    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->response->header('Location', $loginUrl);

}

// Handle the return
public function signupfacebook()
{
    $user = $this->Facebook->Sdk->getUser();

    if($user)
    {
        try
        {
            $facebookuser = $this->Facebook->Sdk->api('/me');

            $this->set('facebookuser', $facebookuser);
        }
        catch(FacebookApiException $e)
        {
            error_log($e);
            $user = NULL;
        }
   }
   else
   {
        $this->Session->setFlash('An error has occurred! Please try again.');

        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
   }
}
```

So a user says I want to authenticate using Facebook and this uses the facebook() method of my controller and then it will ask them for permission and redirect them based on this action. Currently it will just send them to a signup page where some of the fields are pre-filled based on their passed user info like so:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>

    <?php echo $this->Form->input('User.email', array('type' => 'text', 'default'=> $facebookuser['email'], 'label' => array('class' => 'placeholder', 'text' => 'Email address') )); ?>

        <?php echo $this->Form->input('User.firstname', array('type' => 'text', 'default'=> $facebookuser['first_name'], 'label' => array('class' => 'placeholder', 'text' => 'Firstname') )); ?>

        <?php echo $this->Form->input('User.lastname', array('type' => 'text', 'default'=> $facebookuser['last_name'], 'label' => array('class' => 'placeholder', 'text' => 'Lastname') )); ?>

        <?php echo $this->Form->input('User.username', array('type' => 'text', 'default'=> $facebookuser['username'], 'label' => array('class' => 'placeholder', 'text' => 'Username') )); ?>

        <?php echo $this->Form->input('User.password', array('value' => '','type' => 'password', 'label' => array('class' => 'placeholder', 'text' => 'Password') )); ?>

    <button type="submit">Create</button>

<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

**But I have a few issues here:**

**Question 1.)** If the user already has an account in the system with the Facebook credentials they have just entered then it needs to handle this and log the user in. Does this require the use of anything special from the Facebook end? As I'm thinking of just searching the Users table for a matching account and then logging them in automatically, but I've not found any examples online of authenticating your own users table once FB authentication has taken place.

**Question 2.)** Potentially related to previous question, but when a user registers an account, no association with the Facebook account they used to login is saved so if and when they try to login again using Facebook the association won't be seen unless I search the DB for similar details but again this seems very flakey and not the correct use of the API. Essentially the user has just used FB to populate a form and not actually physically signed up using their Facebook account.

I could check if the same email address exists in the DB as the one being passed via Facebook, but what if they have changed it since? I thought about perhaps storing the Facebook user id in a table with the user id in the app so the connection is stored. Would this be a solution? Or the wrong way to do this?

e.g. a new table to store the link between FB Users and CakePHP App Users:

```
id
user_id (this is the relationship to your USER table)
facebook_user_id
```

But even when doing this, not sure how I'd make use of this to properly link the accounts in a useful way and handle the authentication via Facebook correctly instead of just auto-populating the form or logging the user in if certain details match (which I'm sure has potential security risks).

**Question 3.)** When the user is sent back to the signup form via Facebook they get the following URL (note bits have been altered for security reasons):

```
http://domain.com/users/signupfacebook?state=dbf2f6dds322b7cb90d71b6c958a001bf4a3ba&code=AQa7-GDsesM0ZfgswjgGF-mMKwjcoboLl19WKprIA2-f4iZzUdsd8o8z-NweYYODzySS3h9GksBw0G9WCXj79Pp-0ldyeIRCOLSt9gfgfsmEFEfOrEO6gm7a0jmDuQvchdsaHaw1QpI8RdGTCrqAPlLzpHGcqiCtBvXjiQtBhQP--tMr8CIlvRwbrJRwiZwF6xo30howlRkVTLddsdDCDt60_KGznPVmEe-T4Qbu9gdkv9v#_=_
```

From what I can tell based on: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/ I should be creating an extra step between the two methods posted above to handle the code and get an access token back.

**But I have accessed all of the required info I needed to fill out the signup form WITHOUT doing the second stage of the OAuth process and getting an access token!** So not sure if I need it for this circumstance... Or do I? And if so how would it assist in solving the first two questions if it all?

Comment: You wrote: `users can signup either using the app or Facebook and can also login using the app or Facebook`. I can't see what you meant. Could you correct it? By the way, could you clearly say whether you also plan to let users to connect without Facebook? It would mean that you would let the users create accounts and manage passwords.

Comment: Yes the user can create an account without Facebook. But if they do use Facebook then they will still have an account on the application-side that the Facebook user id is linking to.

Answer (score 2):

Following are the steps to allow user to sign up via `facebook`.

Table structure that i have used to done this task is as below,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `profile_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `dob` date NOT NULL,
  `phone_number` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `user_picture` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `profile_view` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `facebook_id` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
  `facebook_status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `login_status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `activation_link` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `password_link` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

First create view file with following code inside. i placed it in `views/users/signup.ctp`

```
<div class="grid_7 alpha">
    <a href="Javascript:void(0);" onclick="connect_facebook(); return false;">
      Signup with facebook
    </a>
</div>
```

apply some css to make it look more beautiful. now inside same view file add following code at the bottom of the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function()
    {
        FB.init(
        {
            appId: FACEBOOK_API,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            oauth: true
        });
    };

    function connect_facebook()
    {
        FB.login(function(response)
        {
            if (response.authResponse)
            {
                $.ajax(
                {
                    url         : HOST+'users/facebook_signup/'+response.authResponse.userID,
                    dataType    : 'json',
                    beforeSend  : function()
                    {
                        $.blockUI({
                            message: '<img src="'+HOST+'img/popup/pre_code_bg.gif" alt="" />'
                        });
                    },
                    success     : function(data)
                    {
                        $.unblockUI();
                        if(data.status == "false")
                        {
                            FB.logout(function(response)
                            {
                                window.location = HOST+'users/logout';
                            });
                            return false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            document.location.reload(true);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                FB.logout(function(response)
                {
                    window.location = HOST+'users/logout';
                    alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                });
            }
        });
    }

    (function()
    {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-signup-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
</script>
```

just replace `FACEBOOK_API` accordingly.

now inside `users_controller` file paste below code,

```
<?php
class UsersController extends AppController
{
    var $name = 'Users';

    function beforeFilter()
    {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow( 'login','signup''facebook_signup' );
    }

    function facebook_signup($facebook_id)
    {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $this->layout = "ajax";

        App::import('Vendor', 'Facebook', array('file' => 'facebook'.DS.'facebook.php'));

        $response = array();

        $facebook = new Facebook(array
        (
            'appId'  => FACEBOOK_API,
            'secret' => FACEBOOK_SKEY,
        ));

        $facebook_user = $facebook->getUser();

        if ($facebook_user)
        {
            try
            {
                $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
            }
            catch (FacebookApiException $e)
            {
                echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
                $facebook_user = null;
            }
        }

        $find_facebookemail = $this->User->find('first',array
        (
            'conditions' => array
            (
                'User.email' => $user_profile['email'],
                'OR' => array
                (
                    'User.facebook_id' => 0,
                    'User.facebook_id' => $facebook_id
                )

            ),
            'recursive' => -1
        ));

        if(!empty($find_facebookemail))
        {
            $this->data['User']['id'] = $find_facebookemail['User']['id'];
            $this->data['User']['email'] = $find_facebookemail['User']['email'];
            $this->data['User']['name'] = $find_facebookemail['User']['name'];
            $this->data['User']['facebook_id'] = $find_facebookemail['User']['facebook_id'];
            $this->data['User']['location'] = $find_facebookemail['User']['location'];
            $this->data['User']['dob'] = $find_facebookemail['User']['dob'];

            $this->Session->write("Auth.User", $find_facebookemail['User']);
            $this->Session->write("Auth.User.facebook_user", true);

            $response['status'] = "true";
            echo json_encode($response);
            exit;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->data['User']['email'] = $user_profile['email'];
            $this->data['User']['name'] = $user_profile['name'];
            $this->data['User']['facebook_id'] = $user_profile['id'];
            $this->data['User']['location'] = $user_profile['location']['name'];
            $this->data['User']['facebook_status'] = 1;
            $this->data['User']['status'] = 1;

            $dob = explode("/",$user_profile['birthday']);
            $this->data['User']['dob'] = $dob[2].'-'.$dob[0].'-'.$dob[1];

            if($this->User->save($this->data['User']))
            {
                $this->Session->write("Auth.User.id", $this->User->getLastInsertID());
                $this->Session->write("Auth.User.name", $this->data['User']['name']);
                $this->Session->write("Auth.User.email", $this->data['User']['email']);
                $this->Session->write("Auth.User.facebook_id", $this->data['User']['facebook_id']);
                $this->Session->write("Auth.User.location", $this->data['User']['location']);
                $this->Session->write("Auth.User.dob", $this->data['User']['dob']);
                $this->Session->write("Auth.User.facebook_user", true);

                $img = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$find_facebookemail['User']['facebook_id'].'/picture?width=500&height=500');
                $img_thumbs = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$find_facebookemail['User']['facebook_id'].'/picture?width=150&height=150');

                $file = "img".DS."user_picture".DS."".$find_facebookemail['User']['facebook_id'].".jpg";
                $file_thumbs = "img".DS."user_picture".DS."thumbs".DS."".$find_facebookemail['User']['facebook_id'].".jpg";

                file_put_contents($file, $img);
                file_put_contents($file_thumbs, $img_thumbs);

                $this->data['User']['id'] = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');
                $this->data['User']['user_picture'] = $find_facebookemail['User']['facebook_id'].".jpg";

                $this->User->save($this->data['User']);

                $response['message'] = "You have successfully registered with us.";
                $response['status'] = "true";
                echo json_encode($response);
                exit;
            }
            else
            {
                $response['message'] = "Something is wrong during process.Please try again later.";
                $response['status'] = "false";
                echo json_encode($response);
                exit;
            }
        }
        exit;
    }
}
```

what controller code do is check if `facebook` user with posted id is **already register** then allow him to `login` to site and set **cakephp auth.user session** and if not then **add user and his/her picture with all other data into mysql database**.

now you have user entry inside your database so you can ask use to change his password once he/she change password then they can `login` to your application without `login` in to `facebook` account.

**Above code is fully tested more than once and its working.**

DONE.

Comment: Never ever store facebook id in an autoincrement field. Let me tell you why, say the controller registers a user of fb id as 121212[1] in the DB, so now when a non FB user registers to app, the id will be 121212[2], this will continue with all non FB users. So when a real user with that id 121212[2] comes, u will have a conflict. Your controller will authenticate the wrong user.

Comment: @KishorKundan have you seen DB.?? i have `facebook_id` bigint(11) NOT NULL,

Comment: Sorry my bad !! :D missed out on tht. 

On a different note, Why are you keeping your controller code so thick ? Your controller code is handling almost every thing that should have been delegated to Model, View and ExceptionHandling.

Comment: @KishorKundan i did it because i just tried to first solve OP problem and then let him know that he can still optimize code as much as OP can...main problem of OP is not controller thickness..so i did not focused on that too much..

Answer (score 1):

**Database Table Structure:** usually you have your regular users table with Name, Email, Birthday, etc and an additional field that contains the Facebook User ID. I call it "facebook_uid". This will serve you for identification purposes related to the Facebook API. If you need to do stuff while the user is logged off your application, then you will need an additional field called "access_token". This access token along with the right permissions will allow you to do things on behalf of the user while he's offline, like post on his wall, etc.

**Answer 1.)** If the user is already registered on your application with Facebook, you just need to check the Facebook User ID coming up in the Facebook API call and match it with your users table. If found, then you handle your local session with CakePHP as you normally would. If it isn't found, it means a new user and they would have to go through the signup process.

**Answer 2.)** The only data you will ever have at hand to associate a manually registered user and a Facebook registered user is their email. If the local email matches the Facebook email, it means its the same user, and you just need to update the "facebook_uid" field on the database, so the next time he logs in, you can already identify him. If the Facebook email is different from the email he used to signup on your site, then you have no way to know its the same person. You could always check other information like name, birthday, and other stuff, but that is not reliable at all and you could mess up your user data. Also, you don't need 2 tables. Your original users table already has the "facebook_uid" field.

**Answer 3.)** Like I explained previously, you will only need the access token if you need to do stuff on the user's Facebook account while he's logged off, like posting on his wall or liking something. In order to get his access token, you just need to call the getAccessToken() method from your Facebook API class:

```
$this->Facebook->Sdk->getAccessToken();
```

This will return a long string that you can store on your users table and then retrieve it to perform tasks on his Facebook account. The following is an example of a Wall post based on CodeIgniter:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
));

$facebook->setAccessToken($row->access_token); //this access token was previously stored in the database

$args = array(
    'message'   => 'Ya estoy participando en el Concurso - Se la Estrella',
    'link'      => $this->config->item('tabUrl'),
    'name'      => 'Concurso - Se la Estrella de Kreisel',
    'caption'   => '¡Vota por mi video! Tu también puedes participar.',
    'picture'   => site_url().'/assets/main/uploads/captures/'.$row->facebook_id.'.jpg'
);

$post_id = $facebook->api("/me/feed", "post", $args);
```

**Also, my personal recommendation regarding your signup form:** do not let the user modify or see his Facebook information on the form, just ask him any additional information you might need that Facebook wont provide, like his phone, company, etc. Information like name, lastname, email, birthday, etc is already on Facebook, and displaying a form with this data already filled will confuse the user. So, if the user is signing up with Facebook, you wont need to ask him him pretty much anything else, just check if the user already exists in your local database, if it does, you log him in, if it doesn't, just save his data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will be reqd to link the accounts together.

I generally add **facebook_id** column for users. So whenever my users want to use FB for login or get positive authenticated response

```
function connectWithFacebook() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    var uid = '';
    var accessToken = '';
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        uid = response.authResponse.userID;
        accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            $.post("http://" + AppSettings.baseURL + "/Users/checkState", 
            {data : response}, 
            function(postResponse){
                if(postResponse == 'registered') {
                    // do after registration stuff
                } else if( postResponse == 'authenticated') {
                        // do after login stuff
                    }
            });
        });
    }
 });
}

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function () {
    connectWithFacebook();
});
```

On the controller side.

```
public function checkState() {
    $userExists = $this->User->userExists($this->request->data['id']);
    if (!empty($userExists)) {         
        $this->authorizeUser($userExists);  // Already exisits, login user to our system with id
        echo "authorized";
        return;
    }
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->create();
        $this->request->data['User']['role_id'] = 4;

        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data, array('validate' => false))) {
            echo "registered";
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

For the users who do not use Facebook to register, the facebook_id column remains 0.

I hope this helps