# No redirect after login via Facebook Login CakePHP

Tags: facebook, cakephp

I am following the [tutorial](http://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/how-to-build-facebook-login-using-cakephp-facebook-login-plugin) to apply FB login in my application. I have completed whole tutorial step by step. There is also button visible on login page "Login via Facebook". But when I click on that button and got autheticated by FB or I am already logged into FB but my page is not redirecting to logged in area. Even after login via FB I remain at login page. But CakePHP login works normal.

Some code snippet from login action of UsersController.php

```
    public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            if($this->Auth->user('id')==1){
                if($this->Auth->user('type')==1){
                    if($this->Auth->user('verified')==0){
                        $this->Auth->logout();
                    }
                }
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Logged In Successfully'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-success'));
            }               
            else{
                $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'index'));
            }              
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-danger'));
    }
}
```

In AppController.php I have included following code:

```
public $components = array(
    'Paginator',
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'index'
        ),
        'logoutRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'home',                
        ),
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish',
                'fields'=>array('username'=>'email') 
            )
        )
    ),
    'Email',
    'Facebook.Connect'
);
var $helpers    = array('Facebook.Facebook');
```

In UsersContoller.php `pr($_SESSION)` output following code when I am already logged in FB on CakePHP login page:

```
    Array
(
    [Config] => Array
        (
            [userAgent] => f04e6*****************c00392
            [time] => 1425647071
            [countdown] => 10
        )

    [fb_989554394440625_user_id] => 8459*********71
)
```

I have searched around the web for this issue but unable to get it solved.

Comment: Hints: 1# Avoid code after a return. This won't be executed. (loginFn) 2# Your 1st logout in loginFn will perform Session-clear which can result in unexpected behaviour

Comment: I have removed the logout from login function, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Anybody here who knows what the problem is?

Comment: can you use X-Debug or usual debug-output to determine, in what if-case it's gonna step out?

Comment: unable to fing using debugging.

Comment: I can strongly recommend getting familar with x-debug for php-development. Its very(!) useful. Anyways can you put a "var_dump('test_1')" and so on for each if-case at its beginning? Then you see how far 'it goes' which might help you find the issue.

Comment: Ok I will try it and let you know.

Comment: Used http://stackoverflow.com/a/15219149/1501051 to do the Signup and login via facebook. Webtechnik plugin was not working fine.

Answer (score -1):

There is missing some important part of code needed to give an qualified, verified answer..

Where are you calling the login-Function? Ensure you only call this if user is NOT logged in, otherwise render your stuff..

```
if(!$this->Auth->user()) {
   $this->login();           // request login
} else {
   $this->render('profile'); //render your view
}
```

This should render the "profile"-View if a user was logged on correctly. If you seem to be logged in but the login-Fn still gets called, you probably made a mistake in overriding Auth-Methods (if you did so)

If you still cannot solve the issue put some more code here.

Comment: I have already solved my problem using the question I have mentioned in comment on question. Regarding code of my question I have provided every line of code which is used for logging in.